# How to allocate order to cells in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro-enabled workbook i've been working on for some time, with the purpose of pulling down TFS items from a server, allocating a business value, then re-ordering the backlog based on what gives the most business value. I've done fine until now, but i've hit a blocker.

I'm trying to allocate a sort order to the adjacent cell for the business value, ordering from highest to lowest. I.e., if the Business Value in that column is highest, the value next to it will be "1", and so forth. An example extract of this is below:

```
BusinessValue (£)
10
17280
384.6153846
0.173611111





8640
3846.153846
```

From the above, I'd expect the value of "17280" to have an associated rank of "1", and the value of "0.1736" to have an associated rank of "6". It seems a very simple expression, and yet i'm having no luck whatsoever in actually getting VBA to do this. Any help would be extremely appreciated, or just pointers.

Edit: Located the answer thanks to the Rank suggestions

Comment: `application.rank` or/ `worksheetfunction.rank` or even a countif should do this.

Comment: What's the rank of the empty rows? 0, 7?  The Rank function would look something like `=RANK(A2,$A$2:$A$12)` - this will give #N/A errors on the blank rows though.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA to do this.  Assuming your values are in `A2:A10`, placing this formula in `B2` and filling down will give you the rank:

```
=RANK.EQ(A2,$A$2:$A$10)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do in fact need it in VBA due to the concept i'm attempting. Thankfully, I did find the answer, and added as an answer

Answer (score 0):

With a bit more useful digging (thank you all for suggesting Rank, as this function was unknown to me), i've managed to come up with the following, which resolves my issue:

```
Sub RankBusinessValue()

    Dim DataSum As Worksheet
    Set DataSum = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    i = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(DataSum.Range("B:B"), ">0")
    For j = 6 To i + 6
        If DataSum.Cells(j, "H").Value > 0 Then
            Range("I" & j).Value = WorksheetFunction.Rank(DataSum.Range("H" & j), DataSum.Range("H6" & ":H" & i + 6), 0)
        End If
    Next j
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [Evaluate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/application-evaluate-method-excel) them all at once (`Summary!` is not needed if used in the VBAProject Sheet Object):

```
Sub RankBusinessValue()
    [Summary!i6:i999] = [if(Summary!j6:j999, Rank(Summary!j6:j999, Summary!j6:j999), "")]
End Sub
```

or to limit the range to the last row:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Long
Set ws = Sheets("Summary")
r = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row        ' last non-empty row in column J

ws.Range("i6:i" & r) = ws.Evaluate(Replace("if(j6:j9, Rank(j6:j9, j6:j9), """")", 9, r))
```